# save current time from date picker for show showing local notifications as a reminder

Tags: ios, datepicker, notifications

In my app i have a screen in which there is a datepicker whose datepicker mode i have set to time. Now when i navigate to this screen, there is also a switch for on and off of setting daily reminders. now first in date picker the current time will show then we can adjust the time by scrolling the datepicker up or down. Lets say i didnt interact with datepicker and simply turn on the switch and click the save button, i want that the current time should be saved i.e lets say the current time was 10:00 PM when i navigate to that screen, then the next day at 10:00PM the notificvation should show and the time should be saved as 10:00PM until or unless i logout from my app. means the datepicker should show the time which the user saved. i have tried but no luck

[scenario when the date picker will be showing current time everytime when you open the app unless you set the differen time by turning the switch on and then setting different time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6rsZ.png)

[scenario when i have only turn on the switch, have not yet interact with the datepicker to adjust time. now when i click save button reminder is not being saved when i again open the app it shows the current time, not the time that was set which is at that time the current time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5k9E.png)

[scenario when i have interact with datepicker and adjust the time and set it, it is working whenever i again opent he app then this time only shows which is correct and everyday at this time the local notification will be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4t8R.png)

my daily reminder screen code:

```
class DailyPracticeVC: UIViewController, NavgationTransitionable
{

    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBOutlet var saveBtn: ZFRippleButton!

    var dateTime = Date()
    var formatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    var isNavigateToSignUpScreen = Bool()
    var isNavigateToCardDeckScreen = Bool()
    var isNavigateToScoreScreen = Bool()

    var c_id = Int()
    var favTag = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Defaults[.isSetReminder]
        {
            saveSwitch.isOn = true
        }
        else
        {
            saveSwitch.isOn = false
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let reminderDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "dateTime") as? Date
        {
            dateTime = reminderDate
            timePicker.setDate(reminderDate, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            timePicker.setDate(Date(), animated: true)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func selectTime(_ sender: UIDatePicker)
    {
        dateTime = sender.date
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.date, forKey: "dateTime")

    }

    @IBAction func switchTapped(_ sender: UISwitch)
    {
        if saveSwitch.isOn
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                if granted
                {
                    print("User gave permissions for local notification..")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Permission denied..")
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    @IBAction func saveNotification(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        animateBtn(toBtn: saveBtn) { (isComplete) in
            if isComplete
            {
                if self.saveSwitch.isOn
                {

                    let now = Date()
                    let calendar = Calendar.current
                    var components: DateComponents? = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: now)

                    self.formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
                    self.formatter.dateFormat = "HH"
                    let hour = self.formatter.string(from: self.dateTime)
                    self.formatter.dateFormat = "mm"
                    let min = self.formatter.string(from: self.dateTime)
                    print(hour,min)

                    components?.hour = Int(hour)!
                    components?.minute = Int(min)!

                    let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                    content.title = "Reminder for studying deck cards!!"
                    content.body = "Remember to study your spanish with Flash Spanish! You’ll be a pro in no time! Study Now >"
                    content.sound = .default
                    content.userInfo = ["value": "Data with local notification"]


                    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components!, repeats: true)
                    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)

                    current.add(request){ (error) in
                        if (error != nil)
                        {
                            self.view.makeToast(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error in local notification")
                        }
                    }

                    self.saveBtn.setTitle("Reminder Saved", for: .normal)
                    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Reminder Saved")

                    Defaults[.isSetReminder] = true

                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                        if Defaults[.UserIsLogin]
                        {
//                            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                            vc.c_id = self.c_id
                            vc.fav_tag = self.favTag
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if self.isNavigateToSignUpScreen == false
                            {
                                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                                vc.c_id = self.c_id
                                vc.fav_tag = self.favTag
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                    current.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ["reminder"])
                    current.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["reminder"])
                    self.saveBtn.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
                    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Reminder Disabled")
                    Defaults[.isSetReminder] = false
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                        if Defaults[.UserIsLogin]
                        {
//                            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                            vc.c_id = self.c_id
                            vc.fav_tag = self.favTag
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if self.isNavigateToSignUpScreen == false
                            {
                                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                                vc.c_id = self.c_id
                                vc.fav_tag = self.favTag
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        playButtonClickAudio()
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you set the picker's time `timePicker.setDate(Date(), animated: true)` looks correct to me. What exactly is the problem? Which date does the picker have?

Comment: lets say first time i open the app, then navigate to reminder screen, then the switch will be off and the date picker will be showing current time unless we set our selves some other time. but what i want that when i just on the switch and directly click save button then the current time should be saved @phi

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your comment, you want to set the picker's date to the current `Date` when the user sets the switch on. You can do that within the `switchTapped` method you already have - just add the code from `viewWillAppear` in there:

```
timePicker.setDate(Date(), animated: true)
```

EDIT: Maybe you want to save the picker's date? Then instead of writing `let now = Date()` in the `saveNotification` method, get the picker's date: `let now = timePicker.date`.

Comment: no its not like that, whether i turn the switch on or off the current time will be showing, on off switch is for if you want to set reminder on or off. but whenever i want to set time then the switch must be turn on then only the time will be set. What i am trying to say that if i turn on the switch and have not interact with datepicker then when click on save button then the current time should also be saved just like its being saved for other time when i set. For example, current time is 10:00  pm and i have set time to 9 pm then 9 pm is being saved

Comment: how can i upload video to SO so that you can understand properly

Comment: you can't upload a video yet, but see my edit in case it helps.

Comment: not working, the time was 12:43 AM when i clicked saved and when came back then it displayed 12:45 AM

Comment: in short it should also save the current time as it is saving for other times if i interact with datepicker. please see the screenshot if it may be clear to you

Comment: u there phi? got any idea on how to solve this issue